# Why am I getting Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , model.list$variables) : undefined columns selected in R?

Tags: r, neural-network

I am getting undefined columns error in R. Here is a description of tran_data

```
train_data <- train[c("DURATION","HOURLY_WAGE", "WAGE_RATE_OF_PAY_FROM_HOUR", "OCCUPATION_NUM","CASE_STATUS_1.0","AGENT_PRESENT_1.0")]
> str(train_data)
data.frame: 70000 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ DURATION                  : num  0.0674 0.0674 0.0449 0.0562 0.0674 ...
 $ HOURLY_WAGE               : num  0.378 0.298 0.387 0.333 0.34 ...
 $ WAGE_RATE_OF_PAY_FROM_HOUR: num  0.396 0.302 0.391 0.333 0.354 ...
 $ OCCUPATION_NUM            : num  0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.3 ...
 $ CASE_STATUS_1.0           : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ AGENT_PRESENT_1.0         : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 ...
```

Code that is throwing an error

```
n <- neuralnet(train_data$AGENT_PRESENT_1.0~train_data$HOURLY_WAGE+
             train_data$DURATION+
             train_data$WAGE_RATE_OF_PAY_FROM_HOUR+
             train_data$CASE_STATUS_1.0+
             train_data$OCCUPATION_NUM,
             data=train_data,hidden = 1)
```

ERROR:
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , model.list$variables) : 
  undefined columns selected

I tried unlist function but I am getting the same error. 
Any help on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you please show the code that gives the error.  One guess is that the column names used for subsetting is different from the ones you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue would be the `formula` needs the unquoted column names and not the values

```
library(neuralnet)
n <- neuralnet(`AGENT_PRESENT_1.0` ~ HOURLY_WAGE+
                  DURATION+
                  WAGE_RATE_OF_PAY_FROM_HOUR+
                  `CASE_STATUS_1.0`+
                   OCCUPATION_NUM,
                 data=train_data, hidden = 1)
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
data(iris)
```

this works

```
n1 <- neuralnet(Species ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris, hidden = 1)
```

this results in error

```
n1 <- neuralnet(iris$Species ~ iris$Petal.Length + iris$Petal.Width, iris, hidden = 1)
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , model.list$variables) : 
>         undefined columns selected